# How to disable/deactivate/archive branches in Perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have a few applications on Perforce and each application has a few branches. Right now only the latest branch is in actual use, the old ones are there for backtracking and debugging purposes.

Is there a way that I can disable the old branches so that no one can branch/use them?

Comment: Do you mean the branch **specs**, or the actual branched **files**? For the specs, you can just delete the specs (perhaps making sure that your spec depot has a copy of them first). For the branched files, if you really don't want others to access them, you could change their protections, or 'p4 delete' them, or even 'p4 obliterate' them, though obliterating should be a last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing permissions to them is the best option.  Since you want them to remain accessible as a historical reference, but NOT permit new changes, you'll want to remove the "write" level of permission but leave the "read" level:

```
write user * * -//depot/oldbranch/...
read  user * *  //depot/oldbranch/...
```

If only some groups have permissions to these branches in the first place you'd need to be careful of the placement of those lines to make sure you don't accidentally grant "read" permission to the other groups; that might mean doing something more like:

```
write group *   * -//depot/oldbranch/...
read  group dev *  //depot/oldbranch/...
```

Or you could use the "=write" syntax instead:

```
=write group * * -//depot/oldbranch/...
```

You can also use "=branch" to prevent the old branch from being used as the source for new branches (the "=branch" permission is included with the "read" level unless you explicitly exclude it like this):

```
=branch group * * -//depot/oldbranch/...
```

For more on setting up permissions: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4sag/chapter.protections.html